# regex read backwards to a full stop in a file path

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Hi im trying to read backwards on a path to extract file extensions. I have managed to get regex to extract everything after a . but the issue is some of the data im dealing with has . in the path so its not giving a true extraction list.

```
\\share\david\test\test.doc
\\sharre\david.jones\test\test.doc
```

im looking to just extract doc from these and in other instances it could also be pptx or docx so i'd like to read back to the .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anchor the regex to the end of the string:

`/\.\w+$/`  or even just `/\w+$/`

https://regex101.com/r/vSyw4Q/1

Comment: This seems to include the . in the extractions. is there a way to just pull out the extension?

Comment: you could actually probably just take out the `\.`

Answer (score 0):

If your extensions only have a single dot, then you should be able to just use the following forward regex:

```
[^.]+$
```

### Demo

Comment: thanks for this however this seems to read everything before the . rather than extracting the .doc extension

Comment: @JonLavercombe Your question wasn't clear, reload the page.  You don't need to do anything in reverse, that feels like a hack to me.